# How to make mask for variable length sequences, which are then padded, in tensorflow2 for RNN

Tags: tensorflow, padding, recurrent-neural-network, masking

Trying implement a mask for a sequence of timeperiods, with zero-padding, to an LSTM network.
Each sequence of timeperiods is of varying length, hence requiring padding & masking.
I am trying to model sequences of length 96(timeperiods), and features=33. Simplified data (7 timeperiods and 3 features) are shown:

example state at a timeperiod = [4, 2, 9] at time0(t0)

example sequence = [[2, 3, 6], [1, 6, 8], [2, 9, 4], [2, 7, 3]] at t(0), t(1), t(2), t(3)

example_padded1 = [[2, 3, 6], [1, 6, 8], [2, 9, 4], [2, 7, 3], 0, 0, 0] at t(0) to t(6)

example_padded2 = [[2, 6, 0], [1, 6, 3], [2, 9, 7], [2, 7, 3], 0., 0., 0.]

example_padded3 = [[2, 6, 0], [5, 8, 3], [9, 4, 7], [2, 5, 3], [0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0.]]

Submitting each example sequence to:

```
seq = example_padded1
masking = layers.Masking(mask_value=0)
masked_output = masking(seq)
print(masked_output._keras_mask)
```

Gives Errors:

padded1 error: InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Pack as input #2(zero-based) was expected to be a
float tensor but is a int32 tensor [Op:Pack] name: packed

padded2 error: InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match:
values[0].shape = [3] != values[2].shape = [] [Op:Pack] name: packed

padded3 error: Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype' when
when checking for mask_value = 0

I then added an input layer to define shape of a sequence:

```
seq_len, n_features = 7, 3
inp = Input(shape=(seq_len, n_features))
masking = layers.Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=inp)
masked_output2 = masking(seq)
print(masked_output2._keras_mask)
```

But got error:
TypeError: Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension.
(Python 3.8, TF2)

Have also been trying Embedding, but that seems even more problematical

How to implement a mask for variable length sequences, which are then padded?

Answer (score 0):

Have possibly resolved this. Problem lies in how I am building the array of sequences.
Each of my sequences consists of:
[array([1,2,3]),array([2,3,4]), array([4,5,6]), array([0,0,0]), , array([0,0,0]), , array([0,0,0]),, array([0,0,0])]
a list of arrays...

when it should be a single array, like:
array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [4,5,6], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]])